# Using nodejs highland in nodejs with mongodb>= 4

Tags: mongodb, highland.js

I'm trying to create a simple highland stream from a Mongo query

```js
const connectionString = ...
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
const records = mongoClient
  .db('mydb')
  .collection('acollection')
  .find({});
const res = await hi(records).tap(_log).collect().toPromise(Promise);

function _log(record) {
  console.log(record);
  return record;
}
```

This code works perfectly with [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) (the npm package) < 4.0.0, but with Mongo >= 4.0.0 it prints an `undefined` over and over until its heap runs out.

I'm running MongoDb in docker, version image `mongo:4.2.10`

Answer (score 0):

See this note from the mongodb 4.0.0 [changelog](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.0/docs/CHANGES_4.0.0.md)

> #### Stream API
>
> The Cursor no longer extends Readable directly, it must be transformed into a stream by calling cursor.stream(), for example:
>
> ```
> const stream = cursor.stream();
> stream.on('data', data => console.log(data));
> stream.on('end', () => client.close());
> ```

So the fix to the issue is to simply add `.stream()` at the end of the mongo query:

```js
const connectionString = ...
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
const records = mongoClient
  .db('mydb')
  .collection('acollection')
  .find({})
  .stream(); // Change is here
const res = await hi(records).tap(_log).collect().toPromise(Promise);

function _log(record) {
  console.log(record);
  return record;
}
```